# 12x24 gable end porch addition

Tags: roofing

I'm adding a gable end porch to my house. I want a 12x24 covering so I have 6x6 post and 2- 2x12 beams attaching to the house on both sides. [image]im using structural trusses so no need for headers. My question is can I cope the beam to lower my porch height? I know I have to support the underside. Rough drawing below for reference. If I don't cope the beam my porch will be 6" taller than the home roof.

Comment: Have you had the trusses made yet? If not, give the truss manufacturer measurements of your current fascia-to-roof peak so they can be made to match the existing roof line.

Comment: Yes they are already made.

Comment: Have you considered reducing the length of the 6X6's? Also, you said cope, do you mean notch?

Comment: Yes sorry I'm an ironworker and that was the only word I could think of calling it lol.

Comment: Reducing the height of the 6x6 would lower that end of the roof but Im wondering about the best way to lower the beam where it connects to the house. Is it acceptable to notch the 2x12 or should I cut the top plate and slide the beam in and support

Comment: I'm not a framer, so I think any suggestions I give should not be used! I will say that notching the beams will reduce the strength of the beam to the equivalent of the left over wood. In other words, if you start with a 2X12 (11 1/4" tall) and you cut a series of 1 1/2" W X 6" tall notches along its length, you essentially have a 5 1/4" tall beam. If you just used a 2 X 6, you'd have 5 1/2". I think lowering the beam will give you better vertical strength, but you have to figure out how to attach it to your house. Good luck with the project!

Comment: Thank you for your advice